# WebActivator error when converting Breeze js code to vb.net

Tags: vb.net, breeze, webactivator

After converting some breeze API from C# code to VB.NET, `WebActivator` throws `Server Error in '/' Aplication` when I run my project with the message:

> The type DevCentralBreeze.HotTowelRouteConfig doesn't have a static
>   method named RegisterHotTowelPreStart

I think I coded everything right - there is a static member, but WebActivator can't find it.

Does anyone know how I can get `WebActivator` to recognize this? Maybe some config issue?

```
Imports System.Web.Http

<Assembly: WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod(GetType(BreezeWebApiConfig),     "RegisterBreezePreStart")> 
Public Class BreezeWebApiConfig
  Public Shared Sub RegisterBreezePreStart()
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(name:="BreezeApi", routeTemplate:="api/{controller}/{action}")
  End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your error is not related to the piece of code that you've posted.

The error refers to `HotTowelRouteConfig` class and missing `RegisterHotTowelPreStart` method. Your code shows `BreezeWebApiConfig` class with `RegisterBreezePreStart` (This is not the method you're looking for... ;-).

Comment: English defeats me yet again... Thanks